# Route queryParam requiring two events and defining a 'global' variable Onit

Tags: angular

My app uses a service and a single component as follows:

**data.service.ts** - this service 'gets' responses from two different api calls and passes a stored route query parameter (id from the route) to one of the api urls:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { course } from './shared/course';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
url_json = 'api url'
url_course = 'api url'

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getMenus() {
  return this.http.get(this.url_course)
}
getContent(id): Observable<course> {
  return this.http.get<course>(this.url_json + '/' + id) //this id comes from the route
}
}
```

**nav.component.ts** - this component does the following:

1. subscribes to a rest api response to display 5 menu components
2. subscribes to a rest api response to display content that is related to each menu item and will display when each menu item is clicked.
3. subscribes to a query parameter that also serves as the id used in one of the rest api calls

   ```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
     import { DataService } from '../data.service';
     import { RouterLink, Router, Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

     @Component({
     selector: 'app-nav',
     templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
     })

    export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

    //iterables for holding data
    menus;
    id;
    content;

    // Query parameters 
    queryParams: Params;

    constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(){
     this.data.getMenus().subscribe((data: {})=> this.menus = data);
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => this.id = params.id)
     }
     get_id(id){
     this.data.getContent(this.id).subscribe((response: {})=> this.content = response)
     console.log(id + ' from nav')
    }
    }
   ```

**nav.component.html** - the route assigns the index id as a queryParam and get_id(id) passes the id value back to the nav component where it is stored to be used with the rest call endpoint.

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; index as id">
    <ul>
        <li><a routerLink = "" [queryParams]="{id: id}" (click)="get_id(id)">{{menu['lessonName']}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div *ngIf="content">
{{content.id}}
</div>
```

Issue: Everything is working as required except for two small bugs and I need some advice or thoughts on the possible issue:

1. id is undefined when the app loads since none of the links have been clicked yet and no query parameters passed. How can I set id with an initial value to prevent this, but still allow it to be updated with a new value when a users clicks on a menu link and the query parameter is stored?
2. This might actually be related to the first issue - every link has to be clicked twice to update the query and the content. Each link is 1 click 'less' than the query parameter value it should assign on the very first click. Clicking a second time updates the value and the related content as needed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make API requests based on a route parameter. This is simply a case of chaining the API call to the observable route.

The `route.queryParams` is a `Subject` that emits a new value when the query params change. And because it's implement with a `BehaviorSubject`, it means you also get an initial value too.

Whatever is dependent on the query params should be chained to the `queryParams` observable with a `switchMap`.

```js
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  //iterables for holding data
  menus;
  content;

  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.data.getMenus().subscribe((data: {}) => this.menus = data);
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      switchMap(params => this.data.getContent(params.id))
    ).subscribe((response: {}) => {
      this.content = response;
    });
  }
}
```

And because your component is now taking care of calling the service when the query params change, you don't need to call it from the HTML.

```html
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; index as id">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink = "" [queryParams]="{id: id}">
        {{menu['lessonName']}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div *ngIf="content">
  {{content.id}}
</div>
```

So now the flow of events is:

- 1a. Load menus
- 1b. Load content based on initial query param
- 2. User clicks on menu link
- 3. Query params are updated
- 4. Your `switchMap` makes a new service call with the latest query param

1a and 1b are not synchronised, but they appear to be independent of each other, so that's not a problem right now.

Normally you would be expected to unsubscribe from subjects, but the router is a special case that cleans up after itself, so you don't have to manually unsubscribe.